# Are there any free algorithmic economic news feeds available?

Tags: data, news

I'm looking to build a news-based trading algo and I need a live news feed for economic data.

Are there are free sources available? I cannot find a single one.

It doesn't have to be perfect, and I'm willing to get my hands dirty and do some development but if anyone has done this before, I would like to know where you got your data and how you were able to make it "live" (that is, did you poll a service, did you scrape a page, or were you able to get a push stream set up somehow?)

As a side, I'm also interested in non-economic news feeds for a stocks strategy. Same question applies (are there any free sources of corporate news and how were you able to make it "live", if it wasnt already build for that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[newsfilter.io](https://newsfilter.io/) provides a real-time financial, and economic news API.

You can easily create rules that the system should use to filter newly incoming articles. For example, you can create a rule as follows

1. If: `symbols` contains `TSLA`
2. Then: speak message `New Article Found! {headline}`

The user interface let's you create such rules very easily (see below). The front-end is connected to the news server via a real-time socket.io channel (a websocket equivalent).

I plan to release a Node.js library soon. You would be able to handle new articles like this:

```
const newsFilterApi = require('api');

newsFilterApi.on('article', article => {
  // do something with new article...
})
```

## Example: Real-Time News Stream

[image]

Comment: Looks dope, thanks for creating this! Would be even better to have economic indicators in numeric form such as this data: https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php . Articles require additional analysis for sentiment, numeric indicators however are immediately actionable for a Forex trading system

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RSS data feed from any reputable source (Bloomberg, TReuters, etc)